# Javascript - increment a var with 1 every one hundred

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I want to increment a var with 1 every 100 presses. I can't write 100 else ifs for every one hundred.

```
    var age = 18;
    var counter = 0;

    function work() {
      counter++;
      if (counter == 100 ) {
      age++;
     } else if (counter == 200) {
      agee++;
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var age = 18;
var counter = 0;

function work() {
    counter++;
    if (counter % 100 == 0) {
        age++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some modulus division:

```js
var age = 18;
var counter = 0;

function work() {
  counter++;
  if (counter % 100 == 0) {
    age++;
    console.log("Age incremented to: " + age + "\nValue of counter: " + counter)
  }
}

for (var step = 0; step < 500; step++) {
  work()
}
```

The `%` symbol essentially just returns the remainder when divided by the other number (aka modulus division).

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **(counter % 100 === 0 )** condition, so whenever there is a counter which is divisible by 100 then it would return true.
% operator - gives the remainder

scenario 1 : counter is between 0 - 99 then no increment in age.

scenario 2 : counter reaches 100 and age get incremented.

scenario 3 : counter is between 101 - 199 then no increment in age.

scenario 4 : counter reaches 200 and age get incremented.

```
var age = 18;
var counter = 200;

function work() {
  counter++;
  console.log("counter "+counter);
  if (counter% 100 === 0 ){
    age++;
  }
  console.log(age);
}
work();
counter = 399; // Just for testing purpose 
work();
```

console.log(age);

Comment: @Alexandru-Cosmin Ghicică, You can Accept an Answer Which Helped You